# How to update Braintree Customer default payment method

Tags: php, payment, braintree

Now what I want to do is show all the `payment methods` a customer used before and let him to choose for the next transaction.

I have successfully fetch all the payment methods, however I find if a customer used use a `PayPal` account before, I can not set a credit card as the default one by use

```
$updateResult = Braintree_PaymentMethod::update(
 ‘credit_card_token',
  [
   'options' => [
   'makeDefault' => true
   ]
  ]
 );
```

or

```
 $updateResult = Braintree_Customer::update(
    $customerId,
    array(
    'creditCard' => array(
      'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
      'options' => array(
          'makeDefault' => true
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

The `drop-in` UI will still show the PayPal account first. Although I can see the this credit card is shift to the default on by query

```
$paymentMethod = Braintree_PaymentMethod::find('token’);
$paymentMethod -> default
```

So my question is can I set directly show credit card as the `default` payment method in drop-in UI even the user use PayPal before?

Answer (score 0):

I work as a developer at Braintree. The Drop-in UI is configured to display the most recently used payment method that was successful, not the PayPal account or the default payment method. Currently, you cannot override this behavior in the Drop-in UI, but the team is working on a way to offer this functionality.

I recommend reading through this related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/23#issuecomment-126123414) to see if any of the proposed alternatives might work for you. You can also subscribe to the issue if you would like to be notified of any updates.

Comment: Also, does it mean that "default" payment method itself doesn't have any useful function at the moment?

Comment: What about the JS UI? The link in your post is to the Android drop-in UI, which has been updated recently. Any information about JS?